# how to send message back to things network using javascript?

Tags: ajax, rest

I want to send message as a ajax request to things network tnn console, to read message. But i am struggling to do this via rest client either as well. Here is my logic to do this below and i would like some help, if i do make a sense, kindly please assist and thanks;

```
<div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
  <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger locked_active">OFF</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
</div> 
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
  </div>
 <br/>

// button for switch functionality on/off.
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle_event_editing button').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('locked_active')) {
      $('#switch_status').html('Switched off');
        $.ajax({
          url:'https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/ttn-eu/api/v2/down/acts083_test/mkr1300?key=ttn-account-v2.7Ph6lBffU7wI9cLY5ljIhIb_I7sqH5EVvo5zs9uVyA0',
          type:'POST',
          data:{
            payload_raw: 'AAA',
            dev_id:'mkr1300'
          },
         success:function(response){
         alert(response);
          },
         error:function() {
           $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request. Please try again");
          }
        }); 

    }else{
    $('#switch_status').html('Switched on.');
    $.ajax({
      url:'https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/ttn-eu/api/v2/down/acts083_test/mkr1300?key=ttn-account-v2.7Ph6lBffU7wI9cLY5ljIhIb_I7sqH5EVvo5zs9uVyA0',
      type:'POST',
      data:{
        payload_raw:'AAE',
        dev_id:'mkr1300'
      },
      success:function(response) {
      alert(response);
      },
      error:function() {
      $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
      }
    });
    }
    });
  });
```

Comment: When you make the AJAX call what response/error you are getting?